# ASP.NET APP cannot log into the Windows event log

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-log

My ASP.NET APP cannot write into the  Windows event log.

I get:

```
{System.UnauthorizedAccessException}
[System.UnauthorizedAccessException]: {System.UnauthorizedAccessException}
HelpLink: Nothing
InnerException: Nothing
Message: "The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be 
searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security."
```

Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to see what identity your application is running as.  It won't necessarily have permissions to write into the event log.

Comment: I'm running on IIS 5.1 so the identity is Machinename\ASP.NET

Where I can add permissions to this identity and what permissions is needed?